# How do I switch the power display on an Godox monolight (e.g., SK400 II) from ratios (1/1) to decimal (10.0)?

Tags: godox, monolights, settings

So, on all the specs I've noticed that with an SK400 II (and most of the other Godox AC-powered manual monolights) that you can set the power not to use ratio settings (1/4, 1/16), but decimal (10.0, 7.2) settings, which would give me 0.1EV increment control over the power, not just 0.3EV control. On the Godox website, in the specs, it says:

[image: specs stating "Power Control" can be 6.0-10.0 or 1/16-1/1]

Since I was used to using these types of settings on other monolights I've used, I was hoping to switch the display. But I don't see any type of control on the lights or anything in [the user manual](http://godox.com/static/upload/file/20220119/1642582851564770.pdf) that will let me do it. Does anybody know how to switch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it on the strobe itself, it's a function of the transmitter. And only two Godox older, manual-only transmitters can do it:

- FT16
- XT16

On the XT16 and FT16, holding down the SET button for two seconds, as demonstrated in [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/1APu9YP0DJU?t=12) toggles the display between ratio and decimal values. (I see no similar function in the Cells II documentation).

But on the other Godox transmitters, the XT32, X2T, and XPro, while you can switch from ratio to decimal display, it only affects the transmitter, not the strobe.

On the XT32, holding down the SET button for two seconds lets you access the following six display modes:

[image: Table from the XT32 manual page table with power settings that combine (ratio/decimal), min. power level (1/128 or 1/256), and increments (0.1EV or 0.3EV)]

Similarly, on the XPro and X2T transmitters, the **STEP** function setting (if the transmitter's firmware is up to date) lets you choose the minimum power setting (1/128 or 1/256), display style (ratio or decimal), and increments (0.1EV or 0.3EV). But unlike the XT32, the only decimal display possible is from 10.0 to min. power; there's no 1.0 to max. power option.

Comment: Changing the display mode with the remote does change it on the strobe as well... (at least w/ the SK400 II)

Comment: @StevenKersting, to clarify, do you mean the XT32, the XPro, or the X2T (or all three)? Godox email support wrote that it didn't work with X2T and XPro, which is why I wrote it this way.  But I'm happy to rewrite it if experience says otherwise.

Comment: I'm only know that the XT16 works that way. I think I misread your answer; you intended it to be the FT/XT-16s will change the setting on both the transmitter and strobe... and assume on the transmitter only with XT32 and later.

Comment: @StevenKersting, yes, that's what I meant. I'll see if I can make that clearer.