# How can I tell if a Godox flash or trigger is compatible with my gear?

Tags: flash, compatibility, godox

I'm looking for a flash trigger for my Canon M50 Mark II that I can connect to a Godox AD600 Pro. I checked some triggers, but the descriptions do not mention if they fit or not. Someone recommended me a trigger with the following description:

"Godox XPro TTL Wireless Trigger, 1/8000s High-Speed-Sync, 5 Dedicated Group Buttons and 11 Customizable Functions (XPro-C Compatible with Canon)"

How do I tell if this is compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Any Godox with the "C" annotation is compatible with the Canon hotshoe protocols.

So you want the X1T-C, X2T-C, XProC, XProIIC, or X3C. Only the last two are current, although the original XproC is still available new. The X3 is very nice and compact; and it has a rechargeable internal battery, which is a +/– kind of thing... pick the one that suits your budget and has the functions you need.

All Godox transmitters are compatible with all Godox receivers such as the one built into your AD600Pro, so that's not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, with an EOS M50 Mark II, all you need to make sure a Godox trigger is compatible is that it's got "X" in its name, and that it's for Canon. So, the XPro-C is compatible with your camera.

Possible versions for the TTL-capable speedlights and triggers that are dedicated to a single camera brand are, from oldest Godox support to newest:

- C (Canon)
- N (Nikon)
- S (Sony)
- O (Olympus/Panasonic micro four-thirds)
- F (Fuji)
- P (Pentax); only for X2T, XPro, R2 Pro II and Xpro II
- L (Leica); only for Xpro II and X3

The Godox X radio system consists of the following gear (at the time I'm writing this):

### Strobes

- **Speedlights**: Any Godox unit that's named with a "TT" or "V" that has **2.4 GHz** radio in its specs.
- **All the AD Witstro lights**
- **P2400**
- **AC-powered monolights**: Any of the strobe series that have 2.4 GHz in their specs.
- **Miscellaneous lights**

  - MF-12 mini macro flashes
  - MFR76 C/N/S TTL macro flash and MFR76S+ Sony dental flash
  - Lux Master [upcoming]
  - FV series CoB LED strobes
  - LF308 panel LED strobe

### Transmitters

Essentially, you are looking for anything with "X" in the name that has 2.4 GHz in its specs. Compatible transmitters in the system (from oldest to newest) at the time I write this:

- XT16 [manual only]
- XT32 [manual+HSS but Canon only]
- X1T
- XPro
- Flashpoint R2 Pro II [US only; Adorama exclusive]
- X2T
- Flashpoint R2 SPT [US only; Adorama exclusive]
- XPro II
- FusionTLC Raven [allows you to combine TTL/HSS Godox radio gear with similar gear from Profoto, PocketWizard, and Paul Buff].
- X3

### Receivers

- X1R.  Only comes in Canon, Nikon, and Sony "flavors" for full TTL communication with an OEM TTL/HSS speedlight (3rd party may have more compatibility issues). Becomes a manual trigger for all other camera systems.
- XTR16.  Only works with Godox strobes that have a dedicated USB-A port for this this or the 433 MHz FTR16 receiver (e.g., AD180, AD360 (Mark I), and AR400 ring flash). Manual only triggering with M power control by group.
- XTR16s.  Only works with Godox speedlights that have the proprietary four-pin connector for it (e.g., V850 (Mark I) and V860 (Mark I). Cannot be used with any other speedlights. Manual-only triggering.

### Commonly-mistaken gear that is NOT in the Godox X system

Godox made a 433 MHz radio flash gear before they created 2.4 GHz X system. This system is not compatible with the X system gear. There are a number of Godox units that are not part of the X system. And the X system does **not** include any radio flash triggers by other brands (e.g., Jinbei (aka Westcott FJ/Rollei HS Freeze), PocketWizard, Profoto, Yongnuo, Neewer Q, Paul C. Buff, Broncolor, or Elinchrom).

- Godox TT560ii/TT520ii (the built-in receiver is 433 MHz)
- Godox TT560 (aka Neewer TT560; no built-in radio)
- Godox Lux Junior, Lux Senior, and Lux Cadet (no built-in radio)
- FT, or CT named radio triggers (433 MHz)
- FC16 (2.4 GHz)
- Cells II (433 MHz)
- AC-powered strobes that are not Mark II or later versions or the MS series (e.g., Mini Pioneers, E series, SK300, etc.). These will not have 2.4 GHz in their specs. The XTR16 receiver can be used, but their ratio power control (e.g., 1/8 power) will *not* be accurate since these lights can only use [decimal control](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130747/how-do-i-switch-the-power-display-on-an-godox-monolight-e-g-sk400-ii-from-ra) (10.0).
- Neewer Q system. (close enough lookalikes to be mistaken as rebranded Godox).